# Ubuntu 12.04 caused Dell d620 wireless to not work

Tags: wireless, dell

I was running 11.xx with the internal b43 wireless.
I have followed all the suggested 
install b43-fwcuttter  firmware-b43-installer   etc.
removed blacklist.conf entry for b43
removed bcmwl-kernel-source

STILL NOTHING....

give me back ubuntu 10 !!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go a completely different route on this answer.  I have had 7 old Dell workhorse laptops ( 600, 610, 620, 6000 all still in use by family and friends) and all running Ubuntu.  The first thing I do with all of them is go to Ebay and order the Intel wireless card that was an option (they all had one).  I decided it was just easier to never ever have to worry about a driver or upgrade again.  I have never paid more than $10 shipped and it seems well worth it. They swap out with a small philips screw driver in about 5 minutes. This answer won't get your running this afternoon so don't expect it to be accepted but as a long term solution I highly recommend it.

Comment: Sounds good.  What model of Intel Wireless card did you get ?

Comment: Just ordered one.   I will give it a go.   The D620 has been a workhorse, but the wireless was always the thorn. Thanks again.

Comment: There were a couple of different ones based on the particular model of computer.  I remember it being quite easy to find by searching. Hope it works as well for you as it has for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have some moral issues with an OS dictating a hardware purchase, especially when the previous [downgraded] version ran the hardware, there's just no excuse for this, I did however use old fashioned instinct and opened up the Synaptic package mangler [pun intended] and typed in Dell. Lo and behold it's a chip-set problem!

After installing the montage of dell system drivers and especially the chipset update whammo!! The wifi card works like a champ. I didn't know Dell had apt-get goodies in our repos but then again something told me to look.

Dell Latitude D620, wn3945ABG wifi card.

Pop out the keyboard and look under it [upper right] if you're in doubt of yours.

Now if your wifi is a different flavor , Broadcom, Lynksys etc... This still might help, Chipset is important for integer and  DMA addressing of hardware.